# LinearLayout changing spinner's height unevenly

Tags: android, spinner, android-linearlayout

I am using a spinner in my project and I upload your information from the database. So far so good, however, in execution the spinner always has its height greater than that of the other components. I looked for several situations here on the stack about how to distribute components equally, but my spinner is stubborn and it seems to me that something else is wrong.

This is my layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/activity_registervalues_message" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textview_valuespoint_pointname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:hint="@string/activity_registervalues_textview_point"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"></EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_valuespoint"
        style="?android:spinnerItemStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Spinner>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textview_valuespoint_pointvalue"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:hint="@string/activity_registervalues_textview_value"
        android:inputType="none|numberDecimal"></EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_valuespoint_novo"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/activity_registervalues_button_novo"></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_valuespoint_save"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/activity_registervalues_button_salvar"></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_valuespoint_close"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/activity_registervalues_button_fechar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_valuespoint"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="textAppearanceFinish">@style/TextAppearanceFinish</item>
    </style>

    <style name="WizardTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="textAppearanceFinish">@style/TextAppearanceFinish</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearanceFinish" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Medium">
        <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In the java class, I have the adapter

```
public ArrayAdapter createArrayAdapter() {
    ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            getSelectedAttributeList()); 

    return spinnerArrayAdapter;
}
```

Why does the height of the spinner change?

EDIT: The screens

Screen in project time

[image: Project time]

Screen in execution

[image: Execution time]

As you can see, in project time the space is equally divided, but in execution time it's possible to see a difference

Comment: Can you share the image, exactly what is happening?

Comment: set layout_width="wrap_content" of your spinner instead of layout_width="fill_parent" and same for all views AND its done ;)

Comment: But in this way the width is different from the other components, getting smaller.

Comment: Look the fields "Clorofila" and "Valor da leitura" in the second screen... the heights is different

Answer (score 0):

fill_parent is Deprecated, you must replace with match_parent or maybe change your implementation and replace with wrap_content.

Think in replace ListView to RecyclerView.

Comment: style="?android:spinnerItemStyle" what define? Has internal set of padding or margin?

Comment: This code didn't work either. It was one of the suggestions I found and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the createArrayAdapter. I should use `simple_spinner_item`

So:

```
public ArrayAdapter createArrayAdapter() {
    ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            getSelectedAttributeList());
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    return spinnerArrayAdapter;
}
```